# python socketserver MyRequestHandller call a function

Tags: python, socketserver

In python,I created a socketserver using socketserver, when I want to call a function in the handle method, it shows that the function is not defined,why is that?

Here is the code:

```
from socketserver import (TCPServer as TCP, StreamRequestHandler as SRH)

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZ = 1024



class MyRequestHandler(SRH):
    def handle(self):
        print('connected from:',self.client_address)
        check()

tcpServ = TCP(ADDR, MyRequestHandler)
print('waiting for connection...')
tcpServ.serve_forever()

def check():
    print('success')
```

Comment: Please post the full trace of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
tcpServ.serve_forever()
```

blocks and

```
def check():
    print('success')
```

is never reached. Move `tcpServ.serve_forever()` call to the bottom of the file (or more generally make it a last command to run).

Answer (score 0):

The function "check()" should actually be a method of the class MyRequestHandler, rather than a function outside the class scope.

That should work:

```
from socketserver import (TCPServer as TCP, StreamRequestHandler as SRH)

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZ = 1024

class MyRequestHandler(SRH):
    def handle(self):
        print('connected from:',self.client_address)
        self.check()
    def check(self):
        print('success')

tcpServ = TCP(ADDR, MyRequestHandler)
print('waiting for connection...')
tcpServ.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Please don't paste Python code into Stack Snippets. The Stack Snippets are made for JS, HTML, and CSS, not Python or any other language.